# Generic class and Constraint

Tags: c#, .net, string, generics

I am working with Generic class and Constraint. Following is my class.

```
public class GenericList<T> where T : new()
    {

        private Node head;

        // constructor 
        public GenericList()
        {
            head = null;
        }

    }
```

when i create object with integer it works fine

```
GenericList<int> list = new GenericList<int>();
```

But when i try with string it gives me following compile time error.

```
GenericList<string> list1 = new GenericList<string>();
```

'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GenericTest.GenericList' 
also when i passed reference parameter like any custom class it works fine.

What is the problem with string?

Comment: Konstantin has explained why it's failing - but why do you have the constraint on T to start with? When do you want to call `new T()`? That's all the constraint enables.

Comment: None of that answers why you'd want the parameterless constructor constraint. Again, when do you want to call `new T()` within `GenericList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) does not have a *public parameterless constructor*..that is why the `new()` constraint is not applicable to it.

Read [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> where T : new()
>
> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When
>   used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be
>   specified last.

Answer (score 2):

It is pointless for `String` type to have public parameterless constructor because `String` is *immutable*, which means that if `String` would have this constructor then it would have to create an empty string object and that is just stupid, because after creation you can not change it.